# How to perform validations in side action class while having multiple submit buttons in single form

Tags: struts2

i have initially 2 fields & submit after validating successfully diplays some more fileds with submit i have to validate these fields in server side 
   so first time i have used validate() for first time  submitted second time i want to do  server side validation.i have to do in single action  ?

```
 <s:form action="some.action" method="post" theme="simple" name="someForm" >
 <td ><s:label value="StdNumber:" /></td>
<td ><s:textfield   name="StdNum"  theme="simple"  /></td>
<td ><s:label value="Date of Birth:"/></td>
<td ><s:textfield  size="10" name="dateOfBirth" id="dateOfBirth" onclick="displayCalendar(document.forms[0].dateOfBirth,'ddd-MM-yyyy',this)" />
<s:submit cssClass="button" value="Submit"  name ="submitbtn" id="submitbtn" method="getEduInfo"  /></td>
<s:if test="sucess">
<td ><s:textfield   name="Stdname"  theme="simple"  /></td>
<td ><s:label value="marks:"/></td>
<td ><s:textfield  size="10" name="marks"  /></td>
<s:submit method="getPersonalInfo" value="submit"/>
 </s:if>
</s:form>
```

Answer (score 2):

To validate the fields differently you should get the name of the button .

In `validate()` you have to write as :

```
if(buttonName.equals(yourFirstButtonName)) { 

     /* validation code for first two fields*/ 

} else if(buttonName.equals(yourSecondButtonName)) { 

     /* validation code for second two fields */

}
```

You can get button name by giving `name` attribute to `s:submit tag` and write `getters` and `setters` to that name .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `annotated validations`.
If we suppose, that you have 2 methods in your action class:
1) `public String getEduInfo() {...}`

2) `public String getPersonalInfo() {...}`

Just use `@Validations` annotation for each of them and place there appropriate validations.

Remember to set `validateAnnotatedMethodOnly` parameter on `true` for `validation` interceptor:

```
<interceptor-ref name="validation">
      <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>
</interceptor>
```

Thanks to that, you can call different validation for different methods.